# issuedTokenAuthentication audienceUriMode=”Never”

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, migrate, ws-federation

I had migrated wcf 3.5 to 4.0 and I had the following error:

"An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message"

A google search lead me to this post:

http://blog.latamhub.com/?cat=3

So, I added the following line and the problem was fixed:

```
<issuedTokenAuthentication audienceUriMode=”Never”>
</issuedTokenAuthentication>
```

I'm not sure what does it do. I'm using wsFederationHttpBinding. 
Does anyone know why it works now?

In wcf 3.5 is a default value and in 4.0 is not?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using wsFederationHttpBinding you are expected to specify target uris for your SAML security token.

Without seeing the the service model code I could not tell you why you had this happen.

You should also enable tracing for Microsoft.IdentityModel and ADFS

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730908

& 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517264.aspx

for more on federation security.